# How to Use Values from an @ElementCollection Map in JPQL Where Clause

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity with a `Map<String,String>` field that is an `@ElementCollection`. I'd like to select entities whose values for this map field match some pattern. However, I'm getting an error at runtime, in this case, with an H2 database.

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "config")
public class Config {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "setting",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "config_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(1024)")
    @Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    Map<String, String> settings;

}
```

Then, in my JPA repository, I have a method that fetches configs which have a setting that matches a given prefix:

```
@Query("select config.id, config.name from Config config " +
        "join config.settings setting " +
        "where value(setting) like concat(:prefix, '%')")
List<List<String>> findConfigBySettingPrefix(@Param("prefix") String prefix);
```

This produces an error from H2:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Scalar subquery contains more than one row;

The SQL generated by the JPQL shows that the `value()` function is expanded into a subselect:

```
select config."id", config."name" from "config" config 
inner join "setting" setting on config."id"=setting."config_id" 
where (select setting."value" from "setting" setting where config."id"=setting."config_id") like (?||'%')
```

Thus, when there are multiple matching settings (as expected), this produces an error because they are being passed into an operator that expects one value. When I wrote the JPQL, I was expecting it would generate something more like this:

```
select config."id", config."name" from "config" config
inner join "setting" setting on config."id"=setting."config_id"
where setting."value" like (?||'%')
```

It would seem I'm not able to use `value()` as a where condition, or I'm just not doing it right. Is there a better way to do this?
I've tried similar variants that all compile at bootup, but they produce the same error at runtime:

```
@Query("select config.id, config.name from Config config " +
        "join config.settings setting on value(setting) like concat(:prefix, '%')")

@Query("select config.id, config.name from Config config " +
        "where value(config.settings) like concat(:prefix, '%')")
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't precisely answer the question, but it is an alternative to using JPQL. Using Spring Data query semantics in the repository method name produces the results I'm looking for:

```
public interface ConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<Config, String> {
    List<Config> findAllBySettingsStartingWith(String prefix);
}
```